# Crear url amigables con htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Buenas necesitaría crear una url amigable, actualmente la dirección es:

```
noticia?ID=TITULARNOTICIA
```

Y necesitaría conseguir que en enlace quedara asi:

```
noticia/TITULARNOTICIA
```

También tengo otro problema a la hora de crear las url amigables que sería conseguir pasar de un enlace así:

```
individual.php?comp=NOMBRECOMPETICION&cat=CATEGORIA
```

Y que quedara un enlace así (en este último necesitaría si es posible que el nombre de la comperición saliera antes del nombre del archivo "individual":

```
NOMBRECOMPETICION/individual/CATEGORIA
```

Muchas gracias de antemano y un saludo

Comment: Hola. Ayer respondí a una pregunta con una problemática similar. Si aún no has resuelto el asunto, vas a encontrar un enfoque que te puede ayudar. [Configuración correcta de htaccess para URLs amigables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/385429/91033)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podré ayudarte en las url amigables.

Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

  # ROUTES

  RewriteRule ^noticia/([0-9a-zA-Z-_-áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ\s]+)$ noticia.php?id=$1 [QSA]

  RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_-áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ\s]+)/individual/([0-9a-zA-Z-_-áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ\s]+)$ individual.php?competicion=$1&individual&categoria=$2 [QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Ahora las url debería de admitir letras mayúsculas, minúsculas y con tildes y diéresis, números, espacios, guiones y guiones bajos:

```
noticia/Éxito%20del%20Asirio%20en%20el%20Andaluz%20de%20Sala
```

```
competicion-lucha-canaria-la-laguna-2020/individual/Lucha
```

Explicación:

- `[0-9a-zA-Z-_-]` -> Hace que puedas añadir números, letras minúsculas y mayúsculas y también el símbolo "_" guión bajo y "-" guion.
- `áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ` -> Para que admita las letras especificadas con tildes y dieresis .
- `\s` -> Para que admita espacios.

El símbolo `$1` y `$2` son los datos que estarán en la url de manera dinámica.

(Me dí el permiso de cambiar el nombre comp y cat para que se leyera mejor, si quieres lo modificas tu ahora)

La bandera [QSA] es para que en la url puedas añadir parámetros GET extra por ejemplo:

```
competicion-lucha-canaria-la-laguna-2020/individual/lucha?buscar=blablabla&filtro=blebleble
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, he probado el código que me dices pero me da el siguiente error: "Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at info@admin.clubasirio.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta, en el apartado RewriteRule ^noticia/, prueba a ver si sigue el error.

Comment: Ahora me sale error 404

Comment: ¿Cuando vas a la url /noticia no pones por ejemplo /noticia/nombre-noticia?

Comment: te mando un ejemplo, usando el enlace http://admin.clubasirio.com/noticia?ID=%C3%89xito%20del%20Asirio%20en%20el%20Andaluz%20de%20Sala si funciona, pero si uso http://admin.clubasirio.com/noticia/%C3%89xito%20del%20Asirio%20en%20el%20Andaluz%20de%20Sala me sale lo de 500 Internal server error

Comment: No se si será porque yo tenía previamente codigo en htaccess para quitar el .php y .html

Comment: son las tildes y los espacios en la url.

Comment: y como podría solucionarlo

Comment: Lo actualicé, creo que funcionará, aunque tambien puedes cambiar esos espacios de la url por guiones, es otra opción.